# getting ip from ping command and storing in batch file variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, ping

Was looking for a way to get the IP address of another computer on the network.    Found this excellent code in another thread:

for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %f in ('ping -4 -n 1 piratelufi.com ^|find /i "pinging"') do echo %f

However, I have 2 issues:

1. Need to be able to run this inside a CMD file.  When I tried, it didn't seem to work.  Everything I read said that it should work, but when I ran the CMD file, nothing happened.
2. I need to be able to store the resulting IP address value in a variable so that I can use it in another command within the same CMD file.  It appears the variable %f already has the value, but when I run this command in a CMD file, and try to access the %f, nothing happens.

Wondering if anyone knows a way to modify this so I run this code in a CMD file and grab that IP for use in another command?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out `for /?` - `%f` is for the command line, `%%f` is for batch scripts

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Has two set PCName lines that you can REM out one and un-REM the other to see that it gives a different IP.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "PCName=piratelufi.com"
REM SET "PCName=google.com"
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%F IN ('PING -4 -n 1 %PCName%') DO SET "PCIP=%%F"
ECHO {%PCIP%}
```

**EDIT:** Thank you to Stephan for pointing out that `FIND` was doing nothing of value, and was actually creating an unnecessary dependency.  `PING` produces only one line that `tokens=2 delims=[]` matches, resulting in only one execution of `DO`. **Above script now has `FIND` removed.** *{My bad for not inspecting the original code for what it was, and was not, doing.}*

Answer (score 0):

In this batch script : We can extract the IP from ping results and we can add a loop if you want to check its state every minute !

---

```bat
@echo off
set "Link=piratelufi.com"
Title Ping Tester for "%Link%"
:MainPing
set "state="
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%b in ('ping -4 -n 1 !Link!') do set "ip=%%b"
    ping -n 1 !Link!>nul && set "state=UP" || set "state=Down"
)
:Myloop
echo. %date% %time% [!Link!] [!ip!] Link is !state!
Timeout /T 60 /NoBreak>nul & goto MainPing
endlocal
```